Turning a Master's Dissertation into a Journal Article
I'm supposed to turn my masters dissertation into a journal article. The journal has no problem with me doing so as long as my work has not been published before, which it hasn't. However, I was wondering whether using word for word from my dissertation would be considered self-plagiarism? and I was hoping for tips on useful links to websites which can explain how to turn my dissertation into an article?
I'm still fresh in the world of academia, so I really have no clue.

Congratulations, that's really cool! Most likely, the journal has a specific audience that you might want to rework or rewrite your thesis work a bit for, on top of wanting to avoid self-plagiarism. There may also be guidelines and style choices that you need to adhere to, for example with regard to manuscript length. Those can usually be found under "Author guidelines" on the journal's website.

As long as your thesis hasn't been published (and in some cases even when it has) you still hold copyright. To avoid self plagiarism what you need to do is cite the thesis, even if generally: "Much of the following is taken verbatim from my thesis...(title, university...)". That makes the origin clear and permits (in theory) a reader to find the original.
I doubt that in a case like this you need to use quotes or paraphrase the earlier work as you have made the origin clear. Rules against self plagiarism (as opposed to the general case) are there to permit backward searches of context, which is only one part of general plagiarism. The key parts of my doctoral thesis were published (by TransAMS) like that.
In theory, but depending on the publisher, it might be possible to just submit the thesis as is for publication.

"Much of the following is taken verbatim from my thesis." I disagree with this advice. Dissertations are regularly turned into one or more publications. Those articles are important for an early scholar's career. The statement you're suggesting would strongly diminish the career value of the article. Also, "self-plagiarism" is a legal term. If the dissertation has not been published by someone who owns the copyright, there is no self-plagiarism and hence no need for such a statement.

@Eggy, Sorry, but this comment seems wrong in every respect. You don't seem to understand self-plagiarism.

I deal with self-plagiarism very often in my work as an academic editor. The poster is specifically referring to how a journal would perceive her submitting her dissertation verbatim. This pertains to copyrights, and to the journal's wish to not republish material that's been published elsewhere. Feel free to be more specific about what you think I misunderstand about self-plagiarism.

How long is your master's dissertation? And what is your main goal in publishing it? Are you intending to pursue a career in teaching and research?
If you're planning on a scholarly career and you think that publishing an article would enhance your career, there are some things to keep in mind. A journal article is a step above your dissertation in prestige. Therefore it needs to demonstrate a new level of skill, namely, the ability to select a narrow topic and write about it concisely, in a compelling way that will be interesting to read.
Second, in my opinion, it's better to create something new for your article, rather than rehashing your thesis verbatim. It's just not that impressive to publish what you've already done, which was probably enhanced by your advisors. "Something new" could mean focusing on a particular subtopic, adding new works to the literature review, expanding the content, and so on.
I don't mean that publishing a summary of your whole topic is necessarily bad, but I recommend that you approach this article as a new piece of writing. At the very least, you will need to shorten your dissertation, which involves selecting the main themes you want to cover and the details you want to include, creating new transitional sentences to connect ideas, reducing excess verbiage to achieve the length limit, reducing the number of tables and figures, and so on.
So here are the steps to follow:
(1) Read the journal's author guidelines. Note the word limit, the required sections of the article, the style (APA, CMS, etc.), subheads, spelling (Britsh vs US),and so on.
(2) Review some sample articles in the journal, noting the writing style and how they're laid out.
(3) Select a topic that fits the journal's scope. Write a very clear and concise topic statement for your own use.
(4) Identify the journal's readership so you can gear your writing to their level of background knowledge of your topic.
(5) Most importantly, make an outline for your article. First list the main sections. Those might be, for example, Abstract, Introduction, Background and Literature Review, Methodology, Results, Discussion, Conclusion. These could be very similar to the sections or chapters in your dissertation. Then make a list of five or so main points under each main subhead.
(6) Recheck your topic statement. Is everything in your outline directly related to your topic statement? Does your outline adequately cover all the important aspects of your topic statement?
(7) Learn what should be covered in each section of the article. The introduction is especially important. Try to avoid saying exactly the same thing in the introduction and conclusion. The conclusion might include a summary of the problem and study results, practical applications or utility of your study, limitations of your study, and recommendations for future research.
(8) Write, revise, format, edit.
(9) As you did with your dissertation, make sure all works cited in the text appear in the reference list and vice versa. Make sure all links in the reference list are current.
(10) Write an email for the journal editor. Briefly describe your paper and why it's important that it be published.
Some or much of the above will vary according to your field and the nature of your research. Hopefully all of the above skills are familiar to you from having written your dissertation.
